# How to return the rowcount of a sql plus query to a separate file

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I am currently running a SQL PLUS script that returns all where it matches and with feedback on it writes this out at the end of the extract.csv file. However is there a quicker way to write the feedback (rows selected) on to a separate file. I have currently just wrapped a count around the query (2nd query) but surely there has to be a quicker way because this is stored on the feedback. just cant find anything online

```
set embedded on
set pagesize 0
set heading on
set linesize 256
set colsep ,   
set trimspool on 
set echo off 
set feedback on 
set termout off
SET UNDERLINE off 

spool C:\extract.csv

select * from stat1 st1
INNER JOIN numbers nmb 
on st1.numb LIKE '%' || nmb.numb || '%';

spool off 

spool C:\count.csv

select count(*) from (select * from stat1 st1
INNER JOIN numbers nmb 
on st1.numb LIKE '%' || nmb.numb || '%');

quit;
```

Comment: What do you need another query to wrap the inner query? move the count inside.

Comment: no i wonder if there is a way to run the first query and then end the spool then spool the number of rows selected on to the second spool

Comment: so for example all i want to output is : 1 file(Extract.csv) with the result of query 1 and then output the rowcount written to file 1 on to a second file (count.csv)

Comment: Your solution is the only solution. Because you want the output in separate files.

Comment: Why do you need the row-count in a separate file?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`

```
spool C:\extract.csv

select * from stat1 st1
INNER JOIN numbers nmb 
on st1.numb LIKE '%' || nmb.numb || '%';

dbms_output.put_line('Got: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);

spool off
```

Also you can create new variable and use `SELECT INTO` for this `SQL%ROWCOUNT` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dbms_output.put_line() command indicated by Darkwing, but have to preceed it with as 'exec' :

```
exec dbms_output.put_line('Got: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that you ought to be able to amend for your purposes:

**test.sql:**

```
set embedded on
set pagesize 0
set heading on
set linesize 256
set colsep ,   
set trimspool on 
set echo off 
set feedback on 
set termout off
SET UNDERLINE off 

variable v_cnt number;

COLUMN cnt NEW_VALUE v_cnt;

spool test_results.txt

select id, count(*) over () cnt
from   (select level id
        from   dual
        connect by level <= 100);

spool off;

execute :v_cnt := &v_cnt;

spool test_cnt.txt

print v_cnt;

spool off;
```

After running the above script:

**Output of test_cnt.txt**

```
 V_CNT
   100
```

**Output of test_results.txt**

```
    ID,       CNT
     1,       100
     2,       100
     3,       100
     4,       100
     5,       100
     6,       100
     7,       100
     8,       100
     9,       100
    10,       100
    11,       100
    12,       100
    13,       100
    14,       100
    15,       100
    16,       100
    17,       100
    18,       100
    19,       100
    20,       100
    21,       100
    22,       100
    23,       100
    24,       100
    25,       100
    26,       100
    27,       100
    28,       100
    29,       100
    30,       100
    31,       100
    32,       100
    33,       100
    34,       100
    35,       100
    36,       100
    37,       100
    38,       100
    39,       100
    40,       100
    41,       100
    42,       100
    43,       100
    44,       100
    45,       100
    46,       100
    47,       100
    48,       100
    49,       100
    50,       100
    51,       100
    52,       100
    53,       100
    54,       100
    55,       100
    56,       100
    57,       100
    58,       100
    59,       100
    60,       100
    61,       100
    62,       100
    63,       100
    64,       100
    65,       100
    66,       100
    67,       100
    68,       100
    69,       100
    70,       100
    71,       100
    72,       100
    73,       100
    74,       100
    75,       100
    76,       100
    77,       100
    78,       100
    79,       100
    80,       100
    81,       100
    82,       100
    83,       100
    84,       100
    85,       100
    86,       100
    87,       100
    88,       100
    89,       100
    90,       100
    91,       100
    92,       100
    93,       100
    94,       100
    95,       100
    96,       100
    97,       100
    98,       100
    99,       100
   100,       100

100 rows selected.
```